# PHP Insert Multiple Checkbox Values Into One MySQL Record

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to figure out how to insert multiple checkbox values into one mysql record. I've tried code snippet after snippet. Maybe someone can take a look at this and tell me what I have done wrong?

NOTE: This is only for my localhost so security is not a concern.

The form:

```
 <form action="newcar.php" method="post">
 Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br />
 Address: <input type="text" name="address"><br />
 City: <input type="text" name="city"><br />
 State: <select name="state">
<option value="AL">Alabama</option>
<option value="AK">Alaska</option>
<option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
<option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
<option value="CA">California</option>
<option value="CO">Colorado</option>
<option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
<option value="DE">Delaware</option>
<option value="DC">District of Columbia</option>
<option value="FL">Florida</option>
<option value="GA">Georgia</option>
<option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
<option value="ID">Idaho</option>
<option value="IL">Illinois</option>
<option value="IN">Indiana</option>
<option value="IA">Iowa</option>
<option value="KS">Kansas</option>
<option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
<option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
<option value="ME">Maine</option>
<option value="MD">Maryland</option>
<option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
<option value="MI">Michigan</option>
<option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
<option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
<option value="MO">Missouri</option>
<option value="MT">Montana</option>
<option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
<option value="NV">Nevada</option>
<option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
<option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
<option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
<option value="NY">New York</option>
<option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
<option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
<option value="OH">Ohio</option>
<option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
<option value="OR">Oregon</option>
<option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
<option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
<option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
<option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
<option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
<option value="TX">Texas</option>
<option value="UT">Utah</option>
<option value="VT">Vermont</option>
<option value="VA">Virginia</option>
<option value="WA">Washington</option>
<option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
<option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
<option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
 </select><br />
 Zipcode: <input type="text" name="zipcode"><br />
 Company: <input type="text" name="company"><br />
 Work Number: <input type="text" name="work"><br />
 Cell Number: <input type="text" name="cell"><br />
 Fax Number: <input type="text" name="fax"><br />
 Insurance: <input type="text" name="insurance"><br />
 Certifications: 
 <input type="checkbox" name="certifications[]" value="FL" />FL
 <input type="checkbox" name="certifications[]" value="NC" />NC
 <input type="checkbox" name="certifications[]" value="NY" />NY
 <br />
 <input type="submit">
 </form>
```

And the php:

```
 <?php
 $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","PASSWORD","pilotcars");
 // Check connection
 if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }

 // escape variables for security
 $Name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['name']);
 $Address = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['address']);
 $City = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['city']);
 $State = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['state']);
 $Zipcode = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['zipcode']);
 $Company = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['company']);
 $Work_Number = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['work']);
 $Cell_Number = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['cell']);
 $Fax_Number = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['fax']);
 $Insurance = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['insurance']);
 $Certifications = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['certifications']);

 $certification=""; 
 $flag=0; 
 foreach($Certifications as $entry){ 
 $certification .= $entry."|"; 
 $flag=1; 
 } 
 if($flag==1){ 
 $certification=rtrim($certification); 
 } 

 $sql="INSERT INTO pilotcarlistings (Name, Address, City, State, Zipcode, Company, Work_Number, Cell_Number, Fax_Number, Insurance, Certifications)
 VALUES ('$Name', '$Address', '$City', '$State', '$Zipcode', '$Company', '$Work_Number', '$Cell_Number', '$Fax_Number', '$Insurance', '$certification')";

 if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
 die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
 }
 echo "1 record added";
 echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=index.php\">";

 mysqli_close($con);
 ?>
```

All of it works except for the multiple check boxes. I am trying to keep the values stored in a single mysql column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$certification = implode('|', $_POST['certifications']);
```

Comment: Where would I put that?

Answer (score 1):

You can join your array using implode then when you want to get the value you can explode it.

Note that there are lots of different ways to do so but at the moment i can think of `implode()`

For example i just made a string out of an array

```
$string = array( 'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h' );

$string = implode( '|', $string );

echo $string;
```

Run the snippet and see the result. In your case you can do the same thing join your array with a separator e.g. | or - ( whatever ) then when you want to deal with it you can explode this string and make an array

Also take a look at php.net information about implode and explode

[Implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

[Explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Good Luck

Comment: How would I use that to store the values? I'm extremely new to databasing.

Comment: Hmm I'm doing some reading on it to try to figure it out. Also since it pertains to this same code lets say I want to pull a record(or multiple) based off of one of the values.  How would I do that? I want to be able to display entries by state sometimes using something like localhost/example.php?state=DisplayAllEntriesWithThisState

Comment: Take a look at my example above. What you wanna do can be achieved using array to string conversion and vice-versa

Comment: I figured out the state thing too. Most of my answers are on google, but putting in the right keywords is taking forever. Thanks guys.